# How to call Pyinstaller via a .bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file, pyinstaller

Currently to use Pyinstaller I open a Python command console then go to the location of my .spec file using `cd` and type `pyinstaller Software.spec`. It works well but I'd like to automate that and have a .bat file do those operations for me.

I have made small .bat files to execute my programs (see below) and I thought the structure for calling Pyinstaller would be close but I'm groping.

```
C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python Software.py
pause
```

Failed attempts of .bat files to run Pyinstaller include:

`C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe Software.spec`

`C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python CALL :pyinstaller Software.spec`

Any idea would be welcome.

## Solution

We need to execute Pyinstaller.exe with Python like so:

```
"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\pyinstaller.exe" "path\to\my\Software.spec"
```

Comment: is `Software.py` in the same directory as the batch file? Also, what did you name your batch file?

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory, that is why I did not specify a path for the .spec or .py files. I called my batch files "EXE Program" and "COMPILE Program" but I doubt it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you need to call the path to the script as well, but also always double quote paths to ensure you do not get some whitespace kreeping in. Always call the full extension name of an executable as good measure.

```
"C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python.exe" "C:\path\to\Software.py"
```

You can also start it, but in the same batch window:

```
start /b "" "C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python.exe" "C:\path\to\Software.py"
```

or with pyinstaller.exe example:

```
"C:\Python\python-3.6.3.amd64\python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" "C:\path\to\Software.spec"
```

Comment: Thanks for the good practice advice. I just realized there was an extra `/python/` in the pyinstaller path so I removed it. Now it finds pyinstaller just fine but I get the famous `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""`

Comment: Remove "" after /b and try again

Comment: So the solution consists of taking my command line for the EXE and replacing `Software.py` with your line `"C:\path\to\pyinstaller.exe" "C:\path\to\Software.spec"`

Answer (score 0):

A simple drag and drop of any python file will result in a compiled exe file in the dist folder created from executing the pyinstaller script.

```
@echo off
PATH = "%PATH% + %USERPROFILE%\AppData\local\programs\python\Python38"
:: %1 is the file dropped on the batch file
pyInstaller --windowed  --onefile %1
```

If you change %1 to the filename it will also work. Save the script as Pyinst.bat then drag and drop a python file onto it.

Comment: The above assumes you are using Python 3.8.0 if you are using a lesser version search appdata \local\programs\python